# jQuery show div by class and id combined

Tags: jquery, html

I got this html:

```
<img src="pics/delete.png" class="showdelete" style="position: absolute; display: none" id="1"
<img src="pics/delete.png" class="showdelete" style="position: absolute; display: none" id="2"
<img src="pics/delete.png" class="showdelete" style="position: absolute; display: none" id="3"
```

And this jQuery so far:

```
function showdelete(z){
    var show = $(z).attr('id');
}
```

Lets say the var is 2. How would the code look complete to show class showdelete with the id 2?

**EDIT**

Ok I got the solution from below but try to hide it again on mouseleave

I tryed:
html:

```
<div class="profilfotos" id="' . $row["id"] . '" onmouseover="showdelete(this)" mouseleave="hidedelete(this)">
```

And jQuery:

```
function hidedelete(z){
    var show = $(z).attr('id');
    $('img[class=showdelete][id='+show+']').hide();
}
```

Comment: Damn it should be onmouseleave instead mouseleave xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : you can use [jquery attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to show div

```
function showdelete(z){
    var show = $(z).attr('id');
    $('img[class=showdelete][id='+show+']').show();
}
```

**EDIT** - you can edit your script like below to work

```
function showdelete(z){
    var show = $(z).attr('id');
    $(".showdelete#"+show).show();
}
```

but as `id` must be unique then you should use id selector directly to show element until and unless you don't have any such requirement to use class selector also

```
function showdelete(z){
        var show = $(z).attr('id');
        $("#"+show).show();
    }
```

Comment: why would you want to combine an id selector with class

Comment: @ArunPJohny, yes you are right until and unless OP has any special requirement for class specific elements. I have updated in my answer. thanks :)

Comment: It's not working, is it maybe because the id's contains dots like "234234.jpg" and so on? Arun because the same id's belong to multiple classes

Comment: I tested it without var like: $(".showdelete#05082014053535.jpg").show(); But it's not working, can I "outcomment" the dot somehow?

Comment: You must not use same `id` for multiple elements, make unique ids. Or share a jsfiddle with your problem statement and will help you better.

Comment: Ok I solved it by taking id's without dots and it works. Could you tell me now how can I hide it again on mouseleave? ^^ I use your first solution

Comment: attach `mouseleave` event and call `.hide()` as in same way as for `.show()`. Share a code how you are calling mouseenter event, I will show you how to add mouseleave code.

Answer (score 0):

If the var is 2 that means $(z) is the target element so there is no need to get the id, you can just use the reference `z` to show the element

```
function showdelete(z){
    //no need to get the id
    //var show = $(z).attr('id');
    $(z).show()
}
```

Note: ID of an element must be unique in a document

Comment: Oh I have same id's in multiple classes, so that is not allowed?